# How do I insert multiple values into a postgres table at once with WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that I am trying to update multiple values at once. Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO movements 
        ( 
                    movements_datetime, 
                    movements_user_id, 
                    movements_product_id, 
                    movements_reason_id, 
                    movements_netto_price, 
                    movements_brutto_price, 
                    movements_quantity, 
                    movements_f 
        ) 
        VALUES 
        ( 
                    '" . date('y-m-dH:I:s') . "', 
                    '" . $id . "', 
                    unnest($product_id), 
                    15, 
                    ( 
                           SELECT product_purchase_price 
                           FROM   products 
                           WHERE  product_id=unnest($product_id)), 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    'false' 
        )
```

ERROR: argument of WHERE must not return a set LINE 1: ...select product_purchase_price from products WHERE product_id... ^

PHP code is

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['actual_stock']); $i++) {
    if($_POST['actual_stock'][$i]!=''){
        $actual_stock[] = $_POST['actual_stock'][$i];
        $product_id[] = $_POST['product_id'][$i];
    }

}


$actual_stock= 'array['. implode(',', $actual_stock). ']';  
$product_id = 'array['. implode(',', $product_id). ']';
```

Comment: Is this a PHP code?

Comment: This is postgresql with "array[10,20,30,40]" array is from php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `VALUES` in this way. If you want to retrieve pairs `(product_id, price)` from `products` you have to query the table, using `any(array)` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select product_id, price
from products
where product_id = any(array[10, 20, 30]);
```

The insert statement should look like this:

```
insert into movements(datetime, user_id, product_id, netto_price)
select '2017-11-21', 1234, product_id, price
from products
where product_id = any(array[10, 20, 30]);
```

Comment: Thank u bro. I used unnecessary unnest with WHERE.